# Console error in tweeter timeline added on website

Tags: javascript, twitter, console, custom-data-attribute, twitter-timeline

I am getting console error in twitter timeline added on website. Twitter timeline is added in following way on website :

```
<div>
                <a href="@Model.TwitterTimeline" class="twitter-follow-button" data-dnt="true" data-show-count="false">@Model.TwitterFollowText</a>
                <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

After digging more, I found that error occurs when poster object(don’t know about it’s source file in twitter) is undefined. Please check below snapshots for error and why it occurs. Please suggest If there is any solution.
[console error in twitter timeline on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2WK5.png)

I checked call stack and chrome inspector and get to know that it is failing at some code in twitter library only. But my point is, do I need to pass anything from my code for example as data attribute or if twitter has updated some thing in their code.